# Segmentation fault when creating a new file in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, fopen

I am confused why this piece of code returns a segmentation fault.
Basically, I try to create a new text file using `fopen()` and `fprintf()`.

```
    void my_function() {
        FILE *g;
        char s1[30];
        printf("\nNew file (text): ");
        scanf("%s",&s1);            //gets(s1);
        g = fopen(s1,"w");
        fprintf(g,"something");
        fclose(g);
}
```

I tried checking the validity of fopen with:

```
if (g == NULL) {
       perror("fopen()");
       exit(1);
    }
```

which returns   `fopen(): Bad address`,so probably that's the problem.
Any idea what caused that and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on `scanf("%s", &s1)`. 
Rather write `scanf("%s", s1);`  because `s1` is already a pointer.

What you have done is passing a pointer to a pointer.